# A summation involving odd integers

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Let $S$ be an odd integer and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^S$ be real coefficients such that $$\sum_{i=1}^S \bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{q-1} b_i = \frac 1q \quad \ \ \ \ \forall q=1,\cdots, S$$

We want to show that the equality is also for $q=S+1$ i.e. $$\sum_{i=1}^S \bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{S} b_i = \frac 1{S+1}$$

I wrote :
$$\sum_{i=1}^S \bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{S} b_i = \sum_{i=1}^S \bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{S-1} \bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)b_i=\frac 1{S-1}\sum_{i=1}^S \bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{S-1} (i-1)b_i$$
$$\iff \sum_{i=1}^S \bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{S} b_i =\frac 1{S-1} \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^S i\bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{S-1} b_i-\sum_{i=1}^S \bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{S-1} b_i \bigg)$$
$$\iff \sum_{i=1}^S \bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{S} b_i = \frac 1{S-1} \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^S i\bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{S-1} b_i- \frac1S \bigg)$$

Now I really do not what to do with the $\sum_{i=1}^S i\bigg(\frac{i-1}{S-1}\bigg)^{S-1} b_i$ that bothers me. I also still did not use the fact that S is an odd integer.

Comment: I think you meant $q=S+1$.  Are you trying to prove something by induction?  If so, you should instead consider $S+2$ as the next odd integer.

Comment: @RobPratt Yes you are right about $q$. It was not an induction but I can do it again in this point of view.